# Single Action Request Without Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make parallel requests of an action for the same user. I'm using Session in my ASP.NET MVC project, so the server will not execute them in parallel.

Searching on the web I found the SessionState attribute for controllers, but I need it for actions. For this I used the ActionSessionStateAttribute and enabled Anonymous request for this action, but I'm having a problem, I'm using **Windows Authentication** in my project and (I don't know why) the response is always the login page before entering in the action.

This behaviour it's similar to FormsAuthentication, but I don't know why Windows Authentication is ignoring `AllowAnonymous`. Why this is happening and how can I solve this? Thanks!

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
public MyController : BaseController
{
    [ActionSessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult GetPartialWithoutSession()
    {
        return PartialView("_Partial");
    }
}
```

Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class ActionSessionStateAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SessionStateBehavior Behavior { get; private set; }
    public ActionSessionStateAttribute(SessionStateBehavior behavior)
    {
        this.Behavior = behavior;
    }

}
```

ControllerFactory:

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override SessionStateBehavior GetControllerSessionBehavior(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            return SessionStateBehavior.Default;
        }

        var actionName = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        MethodInfo actionMethodInfo = controllerType.GetMethod(actionName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (actionMethodInfo != null)
        {
            var actionSessionStateAttr = actionMethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ActionSessionStateAttribute), false)
                .OfType<ActionSessionStateAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (actionSessionStateAttr != null)
            {
                return actionSessionStateAttr.Behavior;
            }
        }
        return base.GetControllerSessionBehavior(requestContext, controllerType);
    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(CustomControllerFactory));
    }
```

Comment: Authorize attribute on controller class is rejecting the request even before it reaches to action

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I tried AllowAnonymous as anotation for the Controller and removing it too.. and didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed one thing, enable anoymous authentication in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

After this, I checked the `PostAcquireRequestState` event handler (can be at Global.asax or http handler), there it was a manually redirect to login page if there's no session attached on the que request.

So if anyone face the same problem, define the same settings I did on the question, enable anonymous authentication and check all events of http request life cycle.